# Paginação - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, estou com um problema ao paginar, os links da paginação são exibidos normalmente, mas independente da pagina que eu ir, os resultados são sempre os mesmos, ou seja, não muda.

**Segue abaixo a função do Controller**

```
    public function index()
{
    if ( ! $this->ion_auth->logged_in() OR ! $this->ion_auth->is_admin())
    {
        redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
    }
    else
    {

        /* Título da Página */
        $this->page_title->push(lang('menu_produtos'));
        $this->data['pagetitle'] = $this->page_title->show();

        /* Breadcrumbs */
        $this->data['breadcrumb'] = $this->breadcrumbs->show();

        /* Paginação */
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config['base_url'] = base_url('admin/produtos/index');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->produtos_model->count('produtos');
        $config['per_page'] = 3;            

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        /* get produtos */
        //$this->data['produtos'] = $this->produtos_model->get('produtos','id,descricao,preco_compra,preco_venda,estoque,estoque_min','');
        $this->data['produtos'] = $this->produtos_model->get('produtos','id,descricao,preco_compra,preco_venda,estoque,estoque_min','',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));

        /* Carrega Template */
        $this->template->admin_render('admin/produtos/index', $this->data);
    }
}
```

**Segue abaixo o Model**

```
    public function get($table,$fields,$where='',$perpage=0,$start=0,$one=false,$array='array'){

    $this->db->select($fields);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->order_by('id','desc');
    $this->db->limit($perpage,$start);
    if($where){
        $this->db->where($where);
    }        
    $query = $this->db->get();

    $result =  !$one  ? $query->result() : $query->row();
    return $result;
}

public function count($table){
    return $this->db->count_all($table);
}
```

**Tabela**

`id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  descricao VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  preco_compra DECIMAL(10,2) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  preco_venda DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
  estoque INT(11) NOT NULL,
  estoque_min INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,`

Comment: Você ja experimentou fazer o debug da instrucao sql pra ver se ela esta sendo gerada corretamente? Use $this->db->last_query() pra recuperar a string da instrucao SQL.  Aí você pega essa string e faz um testes em um SGBD (phpmyadmin, por exemplo) pra ver o que sera retornado.

Comment: Não fiz o debug, e confesso que não sei usar o last_query.
Na verdade não sei onde aplica-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abaixo estou colocando o seu código com a implementação do last_query(), para que você possa fazer o debug.

```
    public function index()
    {
        if ( ! $this->ion_auth->logged_in() OR ! $this->ion_auth->is_admin())
        {
            redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');
        }
        else
        {

            /* Título da Página */
            $this->page_title->push(lang('menu_produtos'));
            $this->data['pagetitle'] = $this->page_title->show();

            /* Breadcrumbs */
            $this->data['breadcrumb'] = $this->breadcrumbs->show();

            /* Paginação */
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $config['base_url'] = base_url('admin/produtos/index');
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->produtos_model->count('produtos');
            $config['per_page'] = 3;            

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            /* get produtos */
            //$this->data['produtos'] = $this->produtos_model->get('produtos','id,descricao,preco_compra,preco_venda,estoque,estoque_min','');
            $this->data['produtos'] = $this->produtos_model->get('produtos','id,descricao,preco_compra,preco_venda,estoque,estoque_min','',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3));
            //EXECUTA O METODO last_query() PARA AUXILIO NO DEBUG
            echo $this->db->last_query();
            //PARA A EXECUÇÃO PARA QUE NADA SEJA IMPRESSO NA TELA, SOMENTE A STRING DA INSTRUÇÃO SQL
            die();

            /* Carrega Template */
            $this->template->admin_render('admin/produtos/index', $this->data);
        }
    }
```

Wagner, dê uma estudada na documentação do CodeIgniter para que você possa fazer um uso mais eficiente dos recursos do framework.

Comment: Sim, eu até li sobre isto, mas não me atentei ao `die();`.
Obrigado!

Comment: Sobre o retorno, não vi problemas, SELECT `id`, `descricao`, `preco_compra`, `preco_venda`, `estoque`, `estoque_min` FROM `produtos` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 3

Comment: Veja que seu SELECT esta retornando somente LIMIT 3, quando ele deveria retornar LIMIT 10, 3 onde 10 é o valor do offset.

Comment: Isto, é aí que está o problema, já tentei definir um `$offset = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;` passando isto para na consulta, e mesmo assim, não funciona.

Comment: Faz um debug no controller, pra ver se esta recuperando o offset que vc pega na url. Depois faz um debug no model pra verificar se ele esta recebendo o parametro do offset e adicionando corretamente na montagem da instrucao SQL. Da uma olhada nesse link, pode te ajudar: http://www.universidadecodeigniter.com.br/paginacao-de-resultados-com-codeigniter-e-bootstrap/

Comment: Descobri o problema, sendo que o teu vídeo ajudou bastante.
O problema estava em `$offset = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;`. Alterei o segmento para 4.

Obrigado

Comment: Legal que o video ajudou!